# Express res.redirect() behaving very strangely

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, node.js-connect

I'm using a customized version of the `vhost` connect/express middleware and inside it I check for the `www` subdomain. If I find that subdomain, then I redirect to the host + path without the `www`. So for example, if I go to `www.google.com` I want to redirect to `google.com`. I call:

```
if (subdomain === "www") {
  res.redirect(req.headers.host.split('.').slice(1).join('.') + req.url);
}
```

However, this redirects me to: `www.google.comgoogle.com` as it appends the new url to the original one. Why is it doing this?

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log()` both `req.headers.host` and `req.url`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try prepending the protocol:

```
res.redirect('http://' + req.headers.host.split('.').slice(1).join('.') + req.url);
```